# Lambda expressions: index of an element in the array

Tags: c#, lambda

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
int oddNumbers = numbers.Count(n => n % 2 == 1);
var firstNumbersLessThan6 = numbers.TakeWhile(n => n < 6);
var firstSmallNumbers = numbers.TakeWhile((n, index) => n >= index);
```

These are C# code taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

I understand the first two lambda expressions just fine by considering n as an element of the array "numbers".

However the third lambda expression is really confusing with "index". Is (n,index) one of the lambda parameters well established for arrays? Is this a convention?

Comment: index meens index of element in array and this expression returns all the elements in the numbers array until a number is encountered whose value is less than its position.OK ?

Comment: It's just part of the delegate that `TakeWhile()` accepts. You can read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548775%28v=vs.100%29.aspx. Check out the *predicate* parameter.

Comment: What did you find when you looked at the documentation of that particular method, and what aspect of that did you find confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `TakeWhile` iterates over the collection:

`n` is the *value* of the element 
  `index` is the *index* of the element

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
// As TakeWhile iterates over the array: 
//   "n" is the value of the element
//   "index" is the index of the element
var firstSmallNumbers = numbers.TakeWhile((n, index) => n >= index);
foreach(var n in firstSmallNumbers)
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Output:

> 5 
>  4

Run this at:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/4NXRkg